# Query syntax works but lambda syntax doesn't for linq select statement

Tags: c#, linq, select

This code doesn't work:

```
return this.Context.StockTakeFacts.Select(stf => ((stf.StockTakeId == stocktakeid) && (stf.FactKindId == ((int)kind)))).ToList<IStockTakeFact>();
```

This statement does:

```
        var f = from stf in this.Context.StockTakeFacts
                where (stf.StockTakeId == stocktakeid) && (stf.FactKindId == ((int)kind))
                select stf;
        return f.ToList<IStockTakeFact>();
```

What is the difference?? The first complains that IQueryable does not have a toList method so I gather I've written the first statement incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `Where` call in order to filter elements (not `Select`)

```
return this.Context.StockTakeFacts
  .Where(stf => ((stf.StockTakeId == stocktakeid) && (stf.FactKindId == ((int)kind))))
  .ToList<IStockTakeFact>();
```

When using explicit LINQ API queries the `select item` is implicit.  It can be made explicit with a call to `Select` but it's not necessary (unless you map the values in some way)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Where()` in order to be able filtering by the predicate:

```
return this.Context.StockTakeFacts
                    .Where(stf => stf.StockTakeId == stocktakeid 
                                  && stf.FactKindId == (int)kind)
                    .ToList<IStockTakeFact>();
```